# MS Word line numbers with a split 1 page document?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, page-layout-view

I have 2 large extracts of text from a story. I would like to fit those extracts side by side on the page with line numbering for each. What is the best way to do this? I am using Microsoft Word 2007

Comment: Do you need the line numbering to start at 1 for both extracts?

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1**

This method will work if you don't need the two extracts to start at line 1.

- Insert a continuous section break in the text at the point where the extracts will be placed.
- Add a blank line
- Insert a second continuous section break in the text.
- Place the cursor on the blank line between the section breaks.
- Enable line numbering for this section (not for the whole document).
- Change to a two-column layout for this section.
- Paste the first extract into the document.
- Insert a column break after the first extract.
- Paste the second extract into the document.
- Put borders around the extracts to highlight them if you like.

The result will look something like this.[image]

It may help to Show Formatting so you can see the location of the section breaks.
[image]

**Method 2**

This method is less flexible and requires more work, but will result in both extracts numbered starting with line 1.

- Paste each extract into a separate Word document.
- Turn on line numbering for the document.
- Set the page width so the text including the line numbers is a bit less than half the page width.
- Take a screen shot of the text.
- Paste the screen shot into the main document.
- Repeat for the second extract.
- Align the screen-shot graphic objects so they line up.